# foreach and Enumeration

Tags: scala

I'm try to learn some Scala reading [Programming Scala, by Dean Wampler](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/index.html).

I'm trying to replicate a code snippet about `Enumeration`

```
object Breed extends Enumeration {
  val doberman = Value("Doberman Pinscher")
  val yorkie = Value("Yorkshire Terrier")
  val scottie = Value("Scottish Terrier")
  val dane = Value("Great Dane")
  val portie = Value("Portuguese Water Dog")
}

for (breed <- Breed) println(breed.id + "\t" + breed)
```

But, in the last line of code, I got this error:

```
value foreach is not a member of object Breed
```

Am I missing something? How can I solve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `.values`:

```
for (breed <- Breed.values) println(breed.id + "\t" + breed)
```

And why not make it a bit more scala-y

```
Breed.values.foreach(breed => println(breed.id + "\t" + breed));
```